# Does every Doctor have a catchphrase? If so what are they?

Tags: doctor-who

What are the catchphrases of the eleven (at the time of this posting) Doctor incarnations in Doctor Who?

For example I know of a few:

1. Chris Eccleston (9th Doctor): *Fantastic!*
2. David Tenant (10th Doctor): *Allons-y!*, *I am so sorry*

Et cetera.

Does anyone have a list of all of the doctor's catchphrases over the years?

Comment: Since the community wiki answer is unfortunately incomplete/incorrect, I wondered if you'd like to reconsider your acceptance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is what I have so far ([taken from here](https://plus.google.com/b/116004737922927360371/116004737922927360371/posts/AzN5D6V1xRB)):

### List by Doctor Number:

1. (William Hartnell): Hmmn. Hmmn. Hmmn.
2. (Patrick Troughton): When I say run.
3. (Jon Pertwee): *nothing comes to mind except* Whomobile
4. (Tom Baker): Care for a Jelly baby
5. (Peter Davison): *nothing again except for* Cricket & Celery
6. (Colin Baker): *got nothing*
7. (Sylvester McCoy): *nothing again*
8. (Paul McGann): Who am I?
9. (Christopher Eccleston): Fantastic
10. (David Tennant):
        - I'm sorry, I'm so sorry
        - Allons-y!
11. (Matt Smith):
         - fezzes/bow-ties/*[random articles of clothing]* are cool
         - Geronimo
12. (Peter Capaldi):
        - Shut up. Shutity shut up.

---

Another list from the [above link](https://plus.google.com/b/116004737922927360371/116004737922927360371/posts/AzN5D6V1xRB):

1st
Doctor Who?
Come along, my dear!
Tut, tut. Dear, dear, dear. Hmmmph!
We can't change history!

2nd
Oh, my giddy aunt!
Oh, dear!
People spend all their time making nice things and then other people come along and break them.

3rd
Did I ever tell you about the time...
Reverse the polarity of the neutron flow!
My dear chap!
A straight line may be the shortest distance between two points, but it is by no means the most interesting.
Allow me to congratulate you, sir. You have the most totally closed mind that I’ve ever encountered.

4th
Would you like a Jelly Baby?
You might be "a doctor" I am "the doctor", the definite article you might say.
There’s no point being grown-up if you can’t be childish sometimes.

5th
Brave heart, Tegan.
I can't free the TARDIS from the time corridor!
What's the problem, old girl? Why this compulsion for planet Earth?
There’s always something to look at if you open your eyes.

6th
Mmmmm. I wonder... Aha!
The TARDIS, when working properly, is capable of many amazing things. Not unlike myself!

In all my travellings througout the universe, I have battled against evil, against power-mad conspirators. I should have stayed here. The oldest civilisation, decadent, degenerate and rotten to the core. Power-mad conspirators, Daleks!, Sontarans, Cybermen!, they're still in the nursery compared to us. Ten million years of absolute power, that's what it takes to be really corrupt!!!!!!

7th
Not this time...
I have made a graaave error of judgement!
If we fight like animals, we die like animals.

8th
Who am I?
I love humans. Always seeing patterns in things that aren’t there.

9th
Fantastic!
I was there...

10th
Allons-y!
I'm so sorry...
I don't want to go!

11th
... is cool. I like ...
Come along, Pond! GERONIMO

GET YOUR COAT!!!

12. (Peter Capaldi):

    - Shut up. Shutity shut up.

Comment: All these answers people are coming up with are great except for one thing the 11th doctor Matt Smith's is blank is cool i wear blank now and the other one that seems to be forgot even though it is one is Geronimo

Comment: I'd add one more for the 10th: "Don't...Just...don't."

Comment: For the 3rd: *Haroun Haroun Haroun* :)

Comment: [Meta discussion about the use of quote marks.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2366/can-this-post-be-locked) Please do not edit either way until this issue is resolved.

Comment: wouldn't a universal one be "I'm the Doctor" or "Because I'm the Doctor!"

Comment: Also Tennet's tendancy to correct himself several times in quick succesion (Well...) i.e. "Nothing here. Well, nothing dangerous. Well, not that dangerous. Know what, I'll just have a quick scan. In case of something dangerous."

Comment: Wouldn't the 11th's be "Yowzah"?

Comment: The Second said "Oh, my word!" quite often.

Comment: Oh, and I see nobody mentioned "What? What? WHAT? WHAT?!"

Comment: @Monty129 Matt Smith did this too. "Anything you say to me can be said in front of Clara. Well, almost anything. Well, around half. Or perhaps a smidgen under. Actually, Clara, would you mind waiting outside?"

Comment: 'I don't want to go' isn't a catchphrase, just a memorable, very 10 quote. He only said it once, so by definition it isn't a catchphrase.

Comment: I came looking for the 12th Doctor's catchphrase and you are absolutely right. :)

Comment: "Reverse the polarity of the neutron flow!" is the one most commonly associated with the 3rd Doctor.

Answer (score 7):

### No.

According to Showrunner and Executive Producer Steven Moffat, the 12th Doctor (Peter Capaldi) **[won't](http://www.mtv.com/news/1905178/doctor-who-peter-capaldi-no-catchphrase/)** have a signature catchphrase and that Matt Smith only had one because he kept ad-libbing it into episodes:

> *“This is a ridiculous thing for me to say in particular, but I don’t
>   like catchphrases very much. They always happen by accident! I never
>   put one in for Matt [Smith]. Matt just liked the word Geronimo, so
>   [he] started shoving it into different scripts where I hadn’t put it.
>   And ’bowties are cool’ was just my nervousness of him wearing a
>   bowtie.”*

Capaldi himself has spoken on this issue in an interview with MTV:

> *Who needs a catchphrase? What’s so great about a catchphrase. **I don’t mind not having a catchphrase!** I have a TARDIS. A Companion.
>   And a crusade. So I’ve got an embarrassment of riches.”*

Comment: This is bad because Catchphrases are cool.