# What would be Colin Baker's doctor(6) catch phrase be

Tags: doctor-who

I can find catchphrases for all of the other doctors but not the sixth. Does he not have a saying just for him?

Answer (score 3):

This question is already sort of answered

[Does every Doctor have a catchphrase? If so what are they?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12685/does-every-doctor-have-a-catchphrase-if-so-what-are-they)

But from a quick search it seems to Colin Baker says Aha! A lot...

He also tends to repeat words...

I found this info from

http://www.tor.com/blogs/2013/10/classic-doctor-who-the-sixth-doctors-essential-episodes

> Catchphrase: “Aha!” Or just any three words or phrases repeated with
>   increasing vigor, ie. “Intolerant. Intolerant? INTOLERANT!!”
>   “Malfunctioning? Malfunctioning? MALFUNCTIONING!?” “Carrot juice.
>   Carrot Juice? CARROT JUICE?!”

Comment: Glad it's _carrot_ juice, not Beetlejuice!